# How do I switch between screens via the menu? A big error appears. Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a navigation controller and several view controllers. When I click on a table cell in the Stocks View Controller, I open the Stock Chart View Controller. In it I have 3 buttons "Chart", "Summary", "News". I want to click on "Summary" to move to the Stock Summary View Controller, but an error occurs for several dozen lines. How can I implement transitions in such a menu?

And how do I click on" back" in Stock Chart View Controller and Stock Summary View Controller to return to Stocks View Controller?

Code for switching from the Stock Chart View Controller to the Stock Summary View Controller:

```
@IBAction func onSummaryButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "StockSummaryViewController") as! StockSummaryViewController

        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Storyboard:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJQp3.png)

Comment: Please, could you add what kind of errors it's causing? It'll help to easily identify what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Your App:
`NavigationVC` > `StocksVC` (tapping on a cell) **➡** `StockChartVC` > `StockSummaryVC` > etc.

**➡** is *important* here, how do you navigate from `StocksVC` to `StockChartVC`? Do you **push** `StockChartVC` or **present modally**? Since you do segues programmatically, it can't bee seen in the image.

I can provide the following info to help you:

- The `push-style` navigation **automatically** contains/adds controls for **backward navigation** because it adds all ViewControllers to its `navigation stack`; all ViewControllers will be embedded in the same `NavigationController`
- In case of presenting scenes `modally`, these ViewControllers have to have their **own** `NavigationController`. thus, your `StockChartVC` has to be embedded in its own `NavigationController`

I believe you do the `push-style` segue from `StocksVC` to `StockChartVC` and also pushing from `StockChartVC` to `StockSummaryVC`; in that case, there should be no problem at all. Moreover (as I wrote), all they VCs will be added controls for backward navigation. Everything will be working just fine!

So pay attention how you are segueing and according to that, implement the right navigation.